# How to get token from server in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to send some data to the server but I got this error:

```
    E/flutter (18058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [403]
E/flutter (18058): #0      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio.dart:966:7)
```

And here is my code:

```
RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        final url = 'https://www.badam.af/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token';
        Dio dio = new Dio();
        final response = await dio.post(
          url,
          data: {
            'username': "admin",
            'password': "mahdi@raham786",
          },
        );

        print("Mahdi: " + response.data);
      },
      child: Text("button"),
    ),
```

I added these permission into manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And also my URL works correctly in the Postman, but in the flutter doesn't work, please help me.

[image: Postman Image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my issue, this error happened because my IP was blocked

```
   E/flutter (18058): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [403]
E/flutter (18058): #0      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio.dart:966:7)
```

I installed a VPN on my cellphone and my issue was fixed.
Thanks my friends for your responses. (-;

Comment: ok. nevertheless, my answer contains an example on how to handle `dio` exceptions properly. If you think this was helpful, please remember to accept the answer.  see [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes, you are right but your answer doesn't fix my issue, sorry (-;

Comment: so then, if your issue was caused by VPN, then your question wasnot relavant to dio at all. you should update your question with an additional note to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3):

Try using `FormData.fromMap`. eg.

```
var data = {
            'username': "admin",
            'password': "mahdi@raham786",
          };
var response = await dio.post(url, data:FormData.fromMap(data));
```

https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata

Comment: Try using the Fiddler tool to inspect raw requests and responses, and compare with you postman request/response to get clues.

Answer (score 2):

your error message indicates that the API call returns `Http status error [403]`
any HTTP call needs to handle both successful responses and failures.

for your code, you can simply do that by `try-catch` and handle exceptions/errors. Additionally, your API seems to expect form-data not a json object.
See code snippet below which should be helpful for your need.

```
var response;  
try {  
  FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "mahdi@raham786",
  });
  response = await dio.post(
          url,
          data: formData,
        );
  // FIXME: use the response as you need  
} catch (e) {
  // FIXME: handle error cases here
    print(e);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work now I got this error:
I/flutter (20465): DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [403]
E/flutter (20465): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.
E/flutter (20465): Receiver: null
E/flutter (20465): Tried calling: data